# strictNullChecks with JSDoc

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm writing an HTML file with some JS code in a `<script>` tag. Since it's directly in the HTML, I can't use TS, so instead I'm using JSDoc to emulate some TS features. One pain point, however, has been that `null` and `undefined` don't like to exist in the type system:

```js
function foo() {
  let x;
  return {
    /** @type {number | undefined} */
    x
  };
}
// inferred return type: { x: number | undefined }

let y = foo();
// inferred type: { x: number }
```

I suspect this is because vs code isn't applying the `strictNullChecks` rule to this script. However, given that it's embedded in an HTML file, I don't think I can use a ts config to set that.

These JSDoc comments are primarily for development convenience (i.e. being able to mouse over something and know its type), so any solution that somehow runs `tsc` on the contents of the script tag doesn't solve the problem at hand.

Is it even possible to fix this?